# adding eventlistner to get file related details

Tags: javascript

I have the following setup in the PHP page for the form fields and when a submit button is clicked, the Javascript function `submit()` is called and the variable 
   `formdata` contains a javascript object.

```
 <!-- Start of HTML Form -->
   <form id = "myForm">
            <label for="projectTitle">Title </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectTitle" value="<?php echo $previousProjTitle;?>" >

            <label for="projectDesc">Description </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectDesc" value="<?php echo $previousProjDesc;?>">
   </form>
   <!-- END of HTML Form -->

   <button  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

   function submit(){  
            var formdata = $("#myform").serializeArray();

    }
```

Now, I want to include file related things in the form fields as follows:

```
<!-- Start of HTML Form -->
   <form id = "myForm">

            <label for="docSubmission">First Document</label>
            <input type="file" id="firstdoc">

            <label for="docApproval">Second Document</label>
            <input type="file" id="seconddoc">

            <label for="projectTitle">Title </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectTitle" value="<?php echo $previousProjTitle;?>" >


            <label for="projectDesc">Description </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectDesc" value="<?php echo $previousProjDesc;?>">


    </form>
    <!-- END of HTML Form -->



    <button  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

So, when my `submit` button is clicked, I am wondering whether it's possible to include document related things (after converting it into base64 format) into the 
    javascript object variable `formdata` ?

I came across [this example](http://jsbin.com/guvudatogu/edit?js,console,output)  where they are converting it into Base64 format by attaching event listner on button click. 
    I am wondering if it's possible to attach event listner somewhere here `<input type="file" id="firstdoc">` or should I be following different approach?

Comment: You're going to want to look into [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Comment: @PHPglue Thanks. This would still be a two-step process, right? I mean upon button click, it won't be getting converted into a javascript object?